# Scala - convert List of Lists into a single List: List[List[A]] to List[A]

Tags: scala, list, recursion, flatten

What's the best way to convert a List of Lists in scala (2.9)?

I have a list:

```
List[List[A]]
```

which I want to convert into

```
List[A]
```

How can that be achieved recursively? Or is there any other better way?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

List has the flatten method. Why not use it?

```
List(List(1,2), List(3,4)).flatten
> List(1,2,3,4)
```

Comment: How will you flatten this

`List(1, List(2,3), 4, List(5,6,7))`

Expected result is 

`List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6,7)`

Comment: the above list is heterogeneous, flatten wont work there. You can do something like: 
List(1, List(2,3), 4, List(5,6,7)).collect{case i:Int => List(i); case l @ a :: b => l}.flatten

Answer (score 13):

.flatten is obviously the easiest way, but for completeness you should also know about flatMap

```
 val l = List(List(1, 2), List(3, 4))
 println(l.flatMap(identity))
```

and the for-comprehension equivalent

```
 println(for (list <- l; x <- list) yield x)
```

flatten is obviously a special case of flatMap, which can do so much more.

Comment: If you want to add in some data during the map this is what you want.

Comment: Interestingly, IDEA suggested I change `listOfLists.flatMap(identity)` to `listOfLists.flatten`.

Answer (score 10):

Given the above example, I'm not sure you need recursion. Looks like you want `List.flatten` instead.

e.g.

```
scala> List(1,2,3)
res0: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> List(4,5,6)
res1: List[Int] = List(4, 5, 6)

scala> List(res0,res1)
res2: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 2, 3), List(4, 5, 6)) 

scala> res2.flatten
res3: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```

Answer (score 7):

If your structure can be further nested, like:

```
List(List(1, 2, 3, 4, List(5, 6, List(7, 8))))
```

This function should give you the desire result:

```
def f[U](l: List[U]): List[U] = l match {
  case Nil => Nil
  case (x: List[U]) :: tail => f(x) ::: f(tail)
  case x :: tail => x :: f(tail)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need recursion but you can use it if you want:

```
def flatten[A](list: List[List[A]]):List[A] = 
  if (list.length==0) List[A]() 
  else list.head ++ flatten(list.tail)
```

This works like flatten method build into List. Example:

```
scala> flatten(List(List(1,2), List(3,4)))
res0: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use flatmap, here is the the way

Suppose that you have a List of List[Int] named ll, and you want to flat it to List,
many people already gives you the answers, such as flatten, that's the easy way. I assume that you are asking for using flatmap method. If it is the case, here is the way

```
ll.flatMap(_.map(o=>o))
```

Comment: How is this answer different from the answer given by Dave Griffith 5 years ago? (Other than the fact that the older answer is cleaner and more concise.)

Comment: You are right, almost the same. I believe that mine is easier to understand or give you some hit for the underline. I am passing a identity function instead of identity keyword. Hope that it makes sense for you

Comment: Will `ll.flatMap(_)` also do the same thing as `ll.flatMap(_.map(o=>o))` ?

Comment: @akki, why don't you try it yourself? It's a moment’s work :). I bet it won't work. Since "underscore" in function literal doesn't describe "identity" function, it means an argument of that function that should be used to describe some logic.  But `_ => _`  will not work either.