# How to convert a List of List to a List in Scala?

Tags: scala

I have a list of list as follows:

```
val xl = (0 until 5).map(i => {Seq(s"$i", s"Mr._$i")}).toList
```

I want to convert it to a list or Seq of strings as:

```
List("0", "Mr._0","1", "Mr._1","2", "Mr._2","3", "Mr._3","4", "Mr._4")
```

I am new to Scala and not able to find any functions in Scala which would help me convert the List of list to a List.

Comment: Hi, looks like your first line does not compile. Do you mean `.map(i => List(s"$i", s"Mr.$i))` (parentheses and not curly quotes ?)

Comment: Updated. I missed the Seq.

Comment: having a look at the documentations you could see `.flatten`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scala - convert List of Lists into a single List: List\[List\[A\]\] to List\[A\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12600863/scala-convert-list-of-lists-into-a-single-list-listlista-to-lista)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use flatMap instead of map:

```
val xl = (0 until 5).flatMap(i => Seq(s"$i", s"Mr._$i"))
```

or

```
val xl = (0 until 5).map(i => Seq(s"$i", s"Mr._$i")).flatten
```

Answer (score 2):

If there is a `flatMap` involved `for-comprehension` is always an elegant way:

```
for{ 
   i <- 0 until 5
   r <- Seq(s"$i", s"Mr._$i")
} yield r
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
val xl = (0 until 5).map(i => List(s"$i", s"Mr._$i")).toList
println(xl.flatten)
```

Output: List(0, Mr._0, 1, Mr._1, 2, Mr._2, 3, Mr._3, 4, Mr._4)

Comment: flatten always guarantees the order of lists?

Comment: Same order than the input I guess. See: https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/immutable/List.html